# What is the right way to perform UI related operations during plugin start

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have a requirement to perform UI operations like 'removing eclipse default menus', 'registering IWindowCloseHandler' and 'adding IWorkbenchListener' etc.

All above mentioned operations are done in plugin `start()` method

```java
start(BundleContext context) {
 ....

Display.getDefault().syncExec(new Runnable() {
 @Override
 public void run() {
    //Disable/Remove eclipse default menu items like Edit, Run etc

    //register workbence register
    final IWorkbench workbench = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();
    final IWorkbenchPage activePage =    workbench.getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
    workbench.getActiveWorkbenchWindow().addPerspectiveListener(pHandler);
    workbench.addWorkbenchListener(new IWorkbenchListener(){                    
        @Override
        public boolean preShutdown(IWorkbench workbench, boolean forced) {
        activePage.closeEditors(activePage.getEditorReferences(), true);
                            return true;
        }
    });     
     //register close handler
     ExitHandler.registerExitHandler();
    }
 }); 
}

public class ExitHandler {
  public static void registerExitHandler() {
     WorkbenchWindow activeWorkbenchWindow = (WorkbenchWindow) PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
    if (activeWorkbenchWindow != null) {
        MWindow window = activeWorkbenchWindow.getModel();
        if (window != null) {
            window.getContext().set(IWindowCloseHandler.class, new IWindowCloseHandler() {

                @Override
                public boolean close(MWindow window) {
                    //Exit logic involves UI;
                }
            });
        }
    }
  }
}
```

At times I am getting below exception for many classes referred in Display.asyncExec()/syncExec():

```
 !MESSAGE While loading class "ExitHandler ", thread "Thread[main,6,main]" timed out waiting (5011ms) for thread "Thread[Thread-6,5,main]" to finish starting bundle "bundlename". To avoid deadlock, thread "Thread[main,6,main]" is proceeding but "ExitHandler " may not be fully initialized.
```

What is the right place to perform these operations ?

1. in earlyStartUp() of org.eclipse.ui.IStartup OR
2. in bundleChanged() of org.osgi.framework.BundleListener OR in lifecycle class.
3. I am doubtful about above two options!! Any other appropriate options ?

Observation: When there is change to my branding plugin, the above issue is observed, else loading is working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed below approaches to solve issues mentioned:

1. Menu enable/disable has been done in init() of my view, which gets loaded after my bundle is started.
2. Registering listeners like 'IWindowCloseHandler' and 'IWorkbenchListener' etc are being done in my 'BundleListener', after bundle is started.

   ```
   public class StudioBundleListener implements BundleListener {
    @Override
      public void bundleChanged(BundleEvent event) {
      String symbolicName = event.getBundle().getSymbolicName();
      int type = event.getType();
      if(symbolicName.equals(MYPlugin.PLUGIN_ID) && type == BundleEvent.STARTED) {
        //Register your listeners
      }
     }
   }
   ```

Both IStartup and async() at the very end of bundle activation code are still causing class load issue as mentioned in question section.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `IStartup` method, but you will need to use `Display.asyncExec` to delay the running of your code until the workbench start up is complete:

```java
public void earlyStartup()
{
  Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      // TODO your code here
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have a class StudioStartup implements IStartup, in which earlyStartup() is implemented. Couple of times I got  "!MESSAGE While loading class "StudioStartup ", thread "Thread[main,6,main]" timed out waiting (5011ms) for thread "Thread[Thread-6,5,main]" to finish starting bundle "bundlename". To avoid deadlock, thread "Thread[main,6,main]" is proceeding but "StudioStartup " may not be fully initialized." and eclipse did not start. The issue is very much intermittent though.

Answer (score 0):

One way to avoid the situation is to put all your code at the very end of your activation code so that you exit very quickly without loading additional classes.

It better to use aysnc execution, since bundle activation thread will return immediate and will go to active state, otherwise bundle activation thread will be blocked until your service gets over.

```
Start(BundleContext context) {
 ....
// this is my last call in the start() method
Display.getDefault().syncExec(new Runnable() {
 @Override
 public void run() {
    //UI logic to disable 
    }
  }
}
```